# CODIGO ZPL PAR ETIQUETAS ZEBRA

Tags: programación-móvil, diseño, impresora, zebra, zpl

Ayudaaaa!!

Estoy revisando un codigo en ZPL para RFID y hay algo que no se si se pueda realizar.

Ejemplo:

Tengo este texto "000ALL-0001234567"

Pero quiero que solo codifique los ultimos 10 digitos: 0001234567

Alguien sabe como? Mis etiquetas solo son 96bits solo permite 12 digitos

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Da la casualidad que esta semana estuve trabajando con estas etiquetas que salen de una BMATH y me pasaron una ZEBRA de Backup y tenia problema con las etiquetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en que hice el cambio para codificar solo los últimos dígitos de texto en ZPL para RFID:

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3^B3N,N,100,Y,N
^FD>;YourDataHere^FS
^FO100,250^ADN,36,20^FD;^FS
^FO300,250^ADN,36,20^FD^SN^FS
^XZ
```

Nota: asegurate de cambiar `YourDataHere` con tu texto, ese código utiliza el comando `^SN` para imprimir el número de serie, y con el comando `^FD` puedes especificar la fuente y el contenido del texto.

Entonces ... Si solo deseas los últimos 10 dígitos, puedes ajustar el texto que va después de `^FD` para que tome un substring. En ZPL, puedes usar `^FN` para definir un campo y luego referenciarlo en varios lugares. Aquí hay un ejemplo actualizado:

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3^B3N,N,100,Y,N
^FD>;^FN1^FS
^FO100,250^ADN,36,20^FD;^FS
^FO300,250^ADN,36,20^FD^SN^FS
^XZ
^XA
^DFE:YOURFORMAT.ZPL
^FO100,100^FDYOURDATAHERE^FS
^FO100,250^ADN,36,20^FD^FN1^FS
^FO300,250^ADN,36,20^FD^SN^FS
^XZ
^XA
^XFE:YOURFORMAT.ZPL
^FN1^FD>:10:10^FS
^XZ
```

Esto asume que tu formato de etiqueta está en `YOURFORMAT.ZPL` y que `YOURDATAHERE` es el texto completo que deseas codificar. La parte importante es `^FD^FN1^FS`, que toma los últimos 10 caracteres del campo definido por `^FN1`.

Comment: Hola, ayúdanos a responder preguntas que sean realizadas con base en [ask], esto para conservar la calidad en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys ok, entonces mi respuesta no es valida?

Comment: o el problema es la pregunta?

Comment: El usuario que pregunta no muestra lo que realizó, en ocasiones estos usuarios empiezan a preguntar más cosas o incluso no valoran la respuesta.

Comment: ok , imagino que es un riesgo que se puede correr, si tengo suficiente contexto como para responder. **por eso pregunto nuevamente, el hecho de que la pregunta sea mala o este mal plantada invalida mi respuesta? espero un si o un no.**

Comment: Se agradece tu esfuerzo Walter!, pero en ocasiones responder a estas preguntas, hace que estos usuarios nuevos no se esfuercen y escriban constantemente preguntas de baja calidad, incluso las respuestas que les dan los usuarios ni siquiera son valoradas por el OP. Lo mejor es preguntar para aclarar y que agregué lo que trato o investigo.

Comment: pero la pregunta es muy simple: ***Hay algo que se pueda realizar***

Comment: Se pueden realizar varias cosas, el usuario requiere opiniones.

Comment: No me parece, yo solo se hacerlo de una forma y en la empresa de Opticon y Zebra solo me enseñaron esta forma ... si hay otras formas de hacer al igual que hay 4 o mas formas de iterrar un array en javascript no quiere decir que este basado en opiniones ... el 99% estaria basado en opiniones si cada desarrollador dice a yo lo hago de otra forma